# Retrofit response retornando null com codigo 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Fala pessoal, to usando Retrofit2 com Kotlin e estou tentando realizar uma requisição POST onde será retornado um Json.

A requisição é feita e a parte do servidor funciona (cadastra o usuario), porem quando vou tratar o response, ele sempre retorna null (com código 406 Not Acceptable)

Requisição feita no Postman:
[image: Requisição feita no Postman]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**RetrofitConfig.kt**

```
class RetrofitConfig(baseUrl: String) {
private val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
private val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
private var retrofit = retrofitBuilder.build()

fun loginService(): LoginService {
    return createService(LoginService::class.java)
}

fun registerService(): RegisterService {
    return createService(RegisterService::class.java)
}

fun <S> createService(serviceClass: Class<S>): S {
    retrofitBuilder.client(httpClient.build())
    retrofit = retrofitBuilder.build()
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass)
}
```

**RegisterService.kt & LoginService.kt**

```
interface RegisterService {
    @POST("registrar/")
    fun registrar(@Body usuario: Usuario): Call<AuthResponse>
}
interface LoginService {
    @POST("login/")
    fun login(@Body usuario: Usuario): Call<AuthResponse>
}
```

**Realizando a Requisição (tanto registrar quanto logar)**

```
override fun logIn(usuario: Usuario) {
    val call = RetrofitConfig(baseUrl).loginService().login(usuario)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<AuthResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, "Sem conexão com a internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthResponse>?, response: Response<AuthResponse>?) {
            val body = response?.body()
            if (response?.isSuccessful == true) {
                if (body!!.sucesso) {
                    usuario.pontuacao = body.pontuacao
                    val it = Intent(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, QuizFragmentRouterActivity::class.java)
                    it.putExtra("usuario", Gson().toJson(usuario))
                    startActivity(it)
                    finish()
                } else Toast.makeText(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, body.mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else Toast.makeText(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, "Ocorreu um erro.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
override fun signUp(usuario: Usuario) {
    val call = RetrofitConfig(baseUrl).registerService().registrar(usuario)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<AuthResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, "Sem conexão com a internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthResponse>?, response: Response<AuthResponse>?) {
            val body = response?.body()
            Log.d("Quiz", "Response: ${response?.code()}")
            if (response?.isSuccessful == true) {
                if (body!!.sucesso) {
                    val it = Intent(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, QuizFragmentRouterActivity::class.java)
                    it.putExtra("usuario", Gson().toJson(usuario))
                    startActivity(it)
                    finish()
                } else Toast.makeText(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, body.mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else Toast.makeText(this@AuthFragmentRouterActivity, "Ocorreu um erro.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: o mapeamento é "registrar", mas você usa "login" no postman

Comment: obtenho o mesmo resultado tanto no registrar quanto no login.

Comment: poste o resultado, e onde é que está o mapeamento do login?

Comment: prints e codigos atualizados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu servidor esta retornando este erro pois não recebeu o parâmetro Accept no header especificando qual o tipo do retorno é esperado.

Na sua interface do Retrofit adicione o seguinte:

```
@Headers({
    "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "User-Agent: Android"
})
```

Referencia para resposta no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http/14252326#14252326).

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, porém também tive que mudar a forma que passava os parâmetros, ao invés de mandar um objeto como Body, mandei os atributos separados como Field. Resolveu.